# C# retrieve fields of type in a collection

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have this class:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    string name { get; set; }
    List<MyClass2> myClass2 { get; set; }
}
```

where `MyClass2`:

```
internal MyClass2
{
    string field1 { get; set; }
    string field2 { get; set; }
    int field3 { get; set; }
    long field4 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve the fields of the `myClass2` via reflection, so I coded the snippet below:

```
Type objectType = typeof(MyClass);
IEnumerable<MemberInfo> members = objectType
    .GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property);

foreach (var field in members)
{
    if (field.Name != "name")
    {
        var fieldT = field.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine("Field: " + field.Name + "; Field type: " + typeof(Property));
        Type propertiesType = field.GetType();
        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> propertiesMembers = typeof(Property)
            .GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property);
                        
            foreach(var property in propertiesMembers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Looking for field: " + field.Name);
                var value = fields.Where(f => f.Key == field.Name).First();
                Console.WriteLine("Actual value receiver for: " + field.Name + " => " + value);
            }
      }
}
```

where `fields` it's just a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` containing non interesting data for the question.

The thing is that I am unable to retrieve the fields in the variable `myClass2`, first, because it's a collection, and second, because in the `fields` variable of the loop, it's determining it's type to `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`.

How can I modify my code to get a collection of the fields inside `myClass2`, yielding the real data that I am looking for? That is just the member info for the `MemberTypes` that are `MemberTypes.Property`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var fieldT = field.GetType();` isn't doing what you think. `field` is a `MemberInfo` instance, so `field.GetType()` will be the same as `typeof(MemberInfo)`.

What you want is the type the property has been declared as, and for that, you'll need to cast to `PropertyInfo` first:

```
Type propertiesType = ((PropertyInfo)field).PropertyType;
```

From there, you can detect when the property is a `List<T>` and reflect over that `T` to get the list of properties on it:

```
foreach (var property in members)
{
    if (property.Name != "name")
    {
        //May be null for some built-in types.
        if (property.DeclaringType == null)
            continue;

        var propInfo = (PropertyInfo)property;

        //If this field refers to a List<T>, get the fields of that lists generic type
        if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType
            && typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(propInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
        {
            var fieldType = propInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var genericListTypeFields = fieldType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var innerField in genericListTypeFields)
                Console.WriteLine($"Found property {innerField.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Found property field1
Found property field2
Found property field3
Found property field4
```

Comment: Sorry about the Public binding, code is edited now to properly reflect the correct question.
Your code works fine, but is printing values like `<name>k__BackingField`. I've tried to change the filter on the members type to it's original, `MemberTypes.Property`, but raises an exception in the casting to `FieldInfo`.  I was able to retrieve the `field.Name` when the Binding is MemeberTypes.Property, but I am unable to merge both codes to avoid parsing the final String (which isn't really a major issue)

Comment: Are you using auto-implemented properties on that type? The C# compiler will automatically add a backing field for those which your code may be picking up.

If you have properties instead of fields, you can cast to `PropertyInfo` instead of `FieldInfo` instead.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the new example code in your question

Answer (score 0):

In order to analyze the properties of `List<MyClass2>`, you can use the following, flexible approach that checks whether a property is assignable to `IEnumerable<T>`. If this is the case, it analyzes `T` (which is `MyClass2` in your case.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var fields = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    AnalyzeProperties(typeof(MyClass), fields, "name");
}

private static void AnalyzeProperties(Type objectType, IDictionary<string, dynamic> fields, params string[] excludedFields)
{
    var members = objectType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var field in members)
    {
        if (excludedFields.Contains(field.Name))
            continue;
        var fieldT = field.PropertyType;
        Console.WriteLine("Field: " + field.Name + "; Field type: " + fieldT);
        // Check whether type is assignable to IEnumerable<T>
        Type genTypeParam;
        if (fieldT.IsGenericType 
            && (genTypeParam = fieldT.GenericTypeArguments.SingleOrDefault()) != null
            && typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genTypeParam).IsAssignableFrom(fieldT))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldT + " is an IEnumerable<" + genTypeParam + ">, analyzing " + genTypeParam);
            AnalyzeProperties(genTypeParam, fields);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Analyze property type
            Console.WriteLine("Looking for field: " + field.Name);
            var value = fields.Where(f => f.Key == field.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Actual value receiver for: " + field.Name + " => " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the code using this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FvFCwE).

Please note that I've made some adjustments to your sample in order to make the property reflection working:

- Changed fields to properties
- Used `GetProperties` instead of `GetMembers`
- Changed binding to `Public`

Please take the code as a sample and adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: Sorry about the Public binding, code is edited now to properly reflect the correct question